# Getting verify error when working with asm java

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation, jvm-bytecode

So basicly Im trying to add a simple `System.out.println("hey");`
at the end of a method. I used the tree API. I do however keep getting this error:

> java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 38

This is my code:

```
public class MethodNodeCustom extends MethodNode {

    public MethodNodeCustom(int paramInt, String paramString1, String paramString2, String paramString3, String[] paramArrayOfString) {
        this(327680, paramInt, paramString1, paramString2, paramString3, paramArrayOfString);
        return;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public MethodNodeCustom(int paramInt1, int paramInt2, String paramString1, String paramString2, String paramString3,
        String[] paramArrayOfString) {
        super(paramInt1);
        this.access = paramInt2;
        this.name = paramString1;
        this.desc = paramString2;
        this.signature = paramString3;
        this.exceptions = new ArrayList((paramArrayOfString == null) ? 0 : paramArrayOfString.length);
        int i = ((paramInt2 & 0x400) != 0) ? 1 : 0;
        if (i == 0)
            this.localVariables = new ArrayList(5);
        this.tryCatchBlocks = new ArrayList();
        if (paramArrayOfString != null)
            this.exceptions.addAll(Arrays.asList(paramArrayOfString));
        this.instructions = new InsnList();
    }
    @Override
    public void visitEnd() {
        AbstractInsnNode label = instructions.getLast();
        instructions.remove(instructions.getLast());
        instructions.remove(instructions.getLast());
        visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", Type.getDescriptor(PrintStream.class));
        visitLdcInsn("Cracked by damm ass pro skills");
        visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
        visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);
        instructions.add(label);

        super.visitEnd();
    }
}
```

And this is my class node:

```
public class ClassNodeCustom extends ClassNode {
    public ClassNodeCustom() {
        super(ASMContentHandler.ASM4);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int paramInt, String paramString1, String paramString2, String paramString3, String[] paramArrayOfString) {
        MethodNode localMethodNode = new MethodNodeCustom(paramInt, paramString1, paramString2, paramString3, paramArrayOfString);
        this.methods.add(localMethodNode);
        return localMethodNode;
    }
}
```

And this is how I "inject" the code (I load it directly from the jar thats why it is using a zipFile)

```
InputStream in = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(in);
ClassNodeCustom node = new ClassNodeCustom();
cr.accept(node, 0);
ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
node.accept(cw);
```

And like I said when ever I run it I get the verify error is there any way for me to solve it or any smarter way for me to "inject" that code ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are adding code at the end of a method, you are adding it after its last instruction which is always a goto, switch, throw or return statement when compiling Java code. Even when compiling a method without an explicit return statement like

```
void foo() { }
```

you are actully compiling

```
void foo() { return; }
```

where the final return is implicit. With your additions, you change the method to

```
void foo() {
  return;
  System.out.println("hey");
}
```

Such unreachable code is forbidden by *javac* but perfectly legal in byte code. For unreachable code, it is however required that you are prepending it with a [stack map frame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.4) that describes the state of the stack and the local variable array at that point. It would be easy enough to add a description of an empty frame at this point but I assume that you want to add the code before the return statement.

To implement this, [ASM offers an `AdviceAdapter`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/commons/AdviceAdapter.html) that allows you to add code before return statements. As far as I know, there is nothing similar for the tree API but you can simply look for a return node within any method's instruction list and add the code prior to it.

Comment: This lines are used to remove the return; instruction and the last label and than readd them AbstractInsnNode label = instructions.getLast();
        instructions.remove(instructions.getLast());
        instructions.remove(instructions.getLast());

Comment: I found my problem thx to your for some reason on my last tests I had to add a certin code at the end of the method so I readded the last instruction of the method after removing it now it seems like I done goofed and added the return code twice .

Comment: Afaik, even the unreachable code would be required to end again with a `return`, `goto` or `athrow` instruction. The verifier just doesn’t get to the point to complain about this due to the missing stack map frame.

Comment: @Holger, I do not think this is true. I just tried this on a recent VM and it does not seem like unreachable code is validated for not falling off the stack.

Comment: How did you try? I just tried with ASM and `COMPUTE_FRAMES` and was a bit surprised by what ASM does with the unreachable code. It’s not sufficient for a prove… Update: I tried with a manually created stack map frame and it *does* throw `java.lang.VerifyError: Control flow falls through code end`. Note that earlier class files w/o stack frames are accepted with unreachable trailing code w/o completion…

Comment: @Holger Here is a quick example run with Java 8: https://gist.github.com/raphw/d90ff0fcc13554872250e9d459c288d4 - I do not use `COMPUTE_FRAMES` and it works out. Strangely enough this invalidates my answer for this question, I do not know what triggers the validation.

Comment: *You* are not using `COMPUTE_FRAMES`, but perhaps this example works, because Bytebuddy uses `COMPUTE_FRAMES` under the hood? Your example doesn’t make clear, how the `ClassWriter` is configured. It’s not even clear whether it produces a version where stack maps are mandatory. In either case, as already hinted in my previous comment, you should disassemble the resulting code, e.g. with `javap -c -v`…

Comment: No, Byte Buddy does not set any hints to ASM, I just use it for simplicity (for me). It is vanilla ASM under the hood but I should of course have mentioned that.

Comment: So…did you disassemble your generated class?

Comment: My bad. Yes I did disassemble the generated class and the stack map frames were as expected but I compiled Java 6 classes as this was mit IDEs preset. As broken stack map frames on these VMs fall back to infered validation if they are considered invalid, I did not get an error. You are right about the validation error when adding dead code.